# How can I import thread package in Python 3?

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading, parallel-processing

I want to import thread package in Python 3.6. But this error is occurred:

```
import thread
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'thread'
```

Answer (score 10):

Change it to `import threading`.

Comment: And use:  `from threading import Thread`                                                                               
&
`Thread(target=method1, args=(arg1,)).start()`

Answer (score 1):

```py
import threading 

def main():
...

if __name__ =="__main__":

    t1 = threading.Thread(target=main, args=())
    t2 = threading.Thread(target=main, args=())
 
    t1.start()
    t2.start()
 
    t1.join()
    t2.join()
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Use the module _thread.

`import _thread`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).